# how to write a regression equation using the output from a summary()

Tags: regression

I am not an expert and I need a help in these commands:

```
lm (growth ~ tannin , data = tanninData)
model <- lm (growth~tannin , data = tanninData)
class ( model )
summary ( model)
```

The question: Write down the regression equation using the output from summary(model)?

Comment: This is a very simple model so you need to know enough about regression to easily write the fitted equation from the output of `summary`.

Comment: thanks , but I am not familiar with R in act I just begin learning it  , and my wondering if there  was a specific command in R to write a regression equation based on the summary output 
you guys are expert in this

Comment: One option is to use the rms package ols function then run the Function function on the fit object to see the model in R notation

Comment: See `?formula` & the manual, [*An Introduction to R*, Ch11](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.pdf) for an explanation of the syntax.

Comment: You could use this function: `write_eqn <- function(model){cf <- signif(coef(model), 2);eqn <- paste("y = ", cf[1], sep="");for (i in 2:length(cf)){;eqn <- paste(eqn, " + ", cf[i],"*", names(cf)[i], sep="")};eqn}` and do `write_eqn(model)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create an object containing your equation:

```
data(mtcars)
eq <-  lm(mpg ~ cyl, mtcars)
```

You can inspect elements inside your `eq` object using the command:

```
str(eq)
```

that returns:

```
List of 12
 $ coefficients : Named num [1:2] 37.88 -2.88
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "(Intercept)" "cyl"
 $ residuals    : Named num [1:32] 0.37 0.37 -3.58 0.77 3.82 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:32] "Mazda RX4" "Mazda RX4 Wag" "Datsun 710" "Hornet 4 Drive" ...
 $ effects      : Named num [1:32] -113.65 -28.6 -3.7 0.71 3.82 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:32] "(Intercept)" "cyl" "" "" ...
 $ rank         : int 2
 $ fitted.values: Named num [1:32] 20.6 20.6 26.4 20.6 14.9 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:32] "Mazda RX4" "Mazda RX4 Wag" "Datsun 710" "Hornet 4 Drive" ...
 $ assign       : int [1:2] 0 1
 $ qr           :List of 5
  ..$ qr   : num [1:32, 1:2] -5.657 0.177 0.177 0.177 0.177 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:32] "Mazda RX4" "Mazda RX4 Wag" "Datsun 710" "Hornet 4 Drive" ...
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "(Intercept)" "cyl"
  .. ..- attr(*, "assign")= int [1:2] 0 1
  ..$ qraux: num [1:2] 1.18 1.02
  ..$ pivot: int [1:2] 1 2
  ..$ tol  : num 1e-07
  ..$ rank : int 2
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "qr"
 $ df.residual  : int 30
 $ xlevels      : Named list()
 $ call         : language lm(formula = mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars)
 $ terms        :Classes 'terms', 'formula'  language mpg ~ cyl
  .. ..- attr(*, "variables")= language list(mpg, cyl)
  .. ..- attr(*, "factors")= int [1:2, 1] 0 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "mpg" "cyl"
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr "cyl"
  .. ..- attr(*, "term.labels")= chr "cyl"
  .. ..- attr(*, "order")= int 1
  .. ..- attr(*, "intercept")= int 1
  .. ..- attr(*, "response")= int 1
  .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
  .. ..- attr(*, "predvars")= language list(mpg, cyl)
  .. ..- attr(*, "dataClasses")= Named chr [1:2] "numeric" "numeric"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "mpg" "cyl"
 $ model        :'data.frame':  32 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ mpg: num [1:32] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
  ..$ cyl: num [1:32] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
  ..- attr(*, "terms")=Classes 'terms', 'formula'  language mpg ~ cyl
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "variables")= language list(mpg, cyl)
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "factors")= int [1:2, 1] 0 1
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "mpg" "cyl"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr "cyl"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "term.labels")= chr "cyl"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "order")= int 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "intercept")= int 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "response")= int 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "predvars")= language list(mpg, cyl)
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "dataClasses")= Named chr [1:2] "numeric" "numeric"
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "mpg" "cyl"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
```

Now, say you want the coefficients of your regressors (the first item of `str()`), use the command:

```
eq$coefficients
```

More specifically, if you want the `intercept`:

```
eq$coefficients[1]
#(Intercept) 
#   37.88458
```

And the coefficient for the `cyl` variable:

```
eq$coefficients[2]
#     cyl 
#-2.87579
```

Etc...

I mean, the R `summary` function is just nice-looking and limited grouping of some elements of an equation object.